# Gaps in HTML Canvas with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, canvas

I'm coding a game with AngularJS and I'm facing a problem with I think a tile size configuration.

Here a screen of my app :

[image: tiles configuration problem screen]

As you see, tiles on the left are splitted by a border and not in the right.
With different screen size it's even more visible.

My map is based on the window size as well as the tiles.

```
// Canvas size
canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight-90; // minus menu size

// Camera size
function Camera(map, width, height) {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.maxX = map.cols * map.tsize - width;
    this.maxY = map.rows * map.tsize - height;
}

// Tile size
tsize: window.innerWidth/20
```

The code is based on the MDN tutorial :
[Link to the Game Development tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/Tilemaps/Square_tilemaps_implementation:_Static_maps)

Comment: Can you put the full code or is it too large?

Comment: It will be too large, but I can post a portion if you want. I have several object : Game to control the whole configuration and render, Camera to display a part of the game, Loader for sprites import, Map object with tile size.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably just due to rounding issues with rendering the tiles. This can be caused by uneven camera positions or zooming.
Try using `ceil()` on the tile size, or just making it slightly larger.

Comment: I tired ceil() and indeed it's a problem of rounding but I thought that having exact size will not create gaps, what is the reason ? I still have my initial problem I'm trying to resolve it with your solution

Comment: With a parsInt() on tsize?